# How can I swap Textures and Materials

Tags: texturing

I just started with Blender after using Max and Maya for years. I am currently at a company that uses a very old modeling program so I was able to 'get' them to install Blender for me, which is awesome.

So far it's a great program but I had a difficult time figuring out how to swap out textures and change up materials etc. It would be great if this was a bit more user friendly. As it is I have to X out the texture that's in there then use Open to go find another one, instead of just using a find texture or replace texture. Is that the only way to do it?

Also is there a way to select poly elements such as the barrel of a gun, instead of just the faces, and then applying a material? In Max you can select elements so thats the only reason I am asking. If theres something similar.

The 3D painter is also awesome! That's primarily what I am using it for.

Added Q's:

1) When I paint in the 3d view and I have a UV/image editor window open, it seems like they don't sync up and they are actually different textures, but I can paint on both of them. I am sure this just takes me getting used to the UI.

2) Is the UV editor window the only place you can save out your textures?

Comment: what render engine are you using? I'm asking because the texturing process and options are different for each.

Comment: I am using Blender Render. Hope that helps.

Comment: You should seriously consider using the Cycles Render engine since you’re going through a learning curve anyway. Cycles is significantly more realistic and in addition the Blender Render engine is being phased out.

Comment: @blarg Welcome to the site. To keep things organized please ask only one question per post. For added questions please ask using a new post. Please read this link: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/504/1853

Comment: I got excited. Sorry for all the questions in the same post. ;)  I am using the normal (?) renderer because these are really low poly models with no extra maps on them unfortunately, just diffuse. :(  So even though I will hit on Cycles, it's not needed right now unless you think it helps.

Comment: There is no reason to use Cycles if you don't want to make realistic renders. For basic renders, if you don't need something fancy, working with Blender Render is faster and it also renders faster as it is more simple. You can start to learn Cycles whenever you will need it.
I highly recommend to watch YT tutorials for beginners, I find Andrew Price good (search "Blender Guru"), also you can read official Blender Manual in the free time :)
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/
One advice - try to not compare it with Max as the workflow in Blender is just different.

Answer (score 2):

**On replacing Textures**

You don't actually have to delete the texture. Instead you can "reassign" the slot by just opening a new one.

Assuming you have already a material with a texture

- Go to Properties Window -> Texture Panel
- Select the desired Texture slot
- Scroll down to "Image"

Now here are two possibilities:

If you want to switch between two textures to chose which one looks better, hit the upper folder button and open a new image texture.

[image: select new texture]

Notice how you now have two textures in your selection box?
If you want to switch between them, just click the selection box and change the texture.

[image: old and new texture to chose from]

If however you want to replace the texture with another one, hit the lower folder button (under Source:)

[image: replace source]

Notice how your original texture got replaced with the new one

[image: replaced texture]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pgqz5.jpg)

**On replacing Materials**

- Go to Properties Window -> Material Panel
- Hit the "+" Button on the right side of the Material Selector. This basically creates a new material slot.
- Select the new slot and hit "New".
- Make changes to your new Material (Textures, colors, whatever)
- With that new material selected Tab into Edit mode and hit "Assign".

[image: change material]

You still have both materials to chose from.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent of 3Ds Max's 'elements' selection mode for Blender currently.

You can however press <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering any vertex, edge or face to select all linked geometry which is the equivalent of an 'element'.

If you already have a geometry selection pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will extend selection to all linked geometry of current selection.